# IBM AMM BladeCenter 39Y9661 problems

Tags: command-line-interface, ibm, update, bladecenter

i'm working on a bladecenter S and i try to update my amm with putty via COM port, but when i want to see my version it doesn't work i use like every time this command:

***env -T system:mm[1]
info***

result > **The target bay is empty.
Unable to read hardware VPD.
AMM slots: 2
Blade slots: 14
I/O Module slots: 4
Power Module slots: 4
Blower slots: 2
Media Tray slots: 1**

***system> list -l a*
system
An unexpected case has arisen - more than ***two MMs*** are present.**

Its weird because only 1 amm is present.Do you have a solution, an idea ? Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution: Just update my amm using a bladecenter H. My amm was in an old version and dont know the Bladecenter S. Regards